# Adding a parameter for 'preference' or 'social validation' in a ranking algorithm currently only using 'time' as a paremeter

Tags: algorithm

I am testing a custom mobile web browser (essentially an extended Android web view). I'm trying out this feature where users are shown a list of recent URLs based on what *other users* viewed recently.

Here's a high level review of how I'm attempting to do this:

1) A URL, the text written inside `<title></title>` in the page's HTML, and a `user_id` form 1 token.

2) I form data packets of 10 tokens at a time (per user) and save it in the back-end.

3) For each new user opening the browser, I have a 'recent searches' section, where I simply show the most recent URLs + titles anyone visited on the browser (sorted by time).

4) I ensure the user's own visited URLs aren't shown them, via filtering out them out through `user_id`.

**My question is:** instead of sorting these URLs purely by recency, how do I add relevancy or popularity to the mix as well, without changing too much of the scheme I've described?

I've already experimented with reddit's and hackernews' ranking algorithms thanks to the excellent explanations [here](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-reddit-ranking-algorithms-work-ef111e33d0d9#.bcmnxlq75) and [here](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-hacker-news-ranking-algorithm-works-1d9b0cf2c08d#.7ud05atl6). Both rely on user votes as a critical input (beside time). That can't apply in my case, since tapping a URL is *not a vote of confidence* by my users. It's likely the user hates the link they visit (or loves it, or is indifferent) - I can't simply 'assume' an upvote for every tap on a URL.

Also, explicit upvoting or downvoting is problematic, since by time the user returns to the list of 'recent URLs' after having clicked one of the entries there, the original entry has been pushed too far down for them to actually find and give feedback on via upvoting/downvoting.

In other words, explicit voting is out, and just tapping a URL doesn't show whether a user approved or disapproved of the URL either.

How do I rank the 'recent URL' listing by anything other than timestamps?

Comment: Doesn't "recent" mean by time?  And if a user visits a site frequently, does it matter whether they like it or hate it?

Comment: Yes 'recent' means by time, though what I'm brainstorming here is a *hybrid* ranking algorithm (different from the reddit/hackernews model which isn't a perfect fit for me). Lastly, regarding the frequency of visits, are you suggesting I add weight for how many times a single URL is visited by the same user?

Comment: Yes. There are sites I have visited many times but not recently.

Comment: But this disincentivizes pages you may visit once (because of fresh, new content that's only relevant *now*), but which are very popular. E.g. a news item or an NBA play of the day.